# php array, to check if a value at key is set or not and update accordingly

Tags: php, arrays, boolean, isset

I initialize a php array named $present, the purpose of this array is to hold the value of 1 if a name is present or zero if the name is absent. i have a name array of size 10. below is the code mentioned, but it is not working.

```
$present = Array();
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
    if(!isset($present[$name[$i]])) {
       $present[$name] = 1;
     }
     else echo $present[$name[$i]];
}
```

i have also tried this :

```
$present = Array();
    for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
        if(empty($present[$name[$i]])) {
           $present[$name] = 1;
         }
         else echo $present[$name[$i]];
    }
```

please help thanks!

Comment: why are you first using `$name[$i]` and then `$name` ?

Comment: `$present` is empty in the start of these examples, should it be? and what is `$names`?  we could use a desired input/output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for. You're missing the $i when setting it to 1.

```
$present = array();
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
    if(!isset($present[$name[$i]])) {
       $present[$name[$i]] = 1;
     }
     else echo $present[$name[$i]];
}
```

Comment: but there are no set elements in `$present`  he needs to tell us more

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
$present = Array();
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
  if(!isset($present[$name[$i]])) {
       $present[$name[$i]] = 1;
     }
     else echo $present[$name[$i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but if you just want to keep track of whether a name is present or not, you could just make $present be an array of names, and then use in_array.

```
$present = array('John', 'Paul', 'George');

echo in_array('John', $present);          # returns 1
echo in_array('MacArthur', $present);     #returns 0
```